# Ansible gather_facts, how does it gather details about a linux OS

Tags: ansible

My question is simple, what command or how does ansible internally executes to gather the system information like ansible_os_family, ansible_distribution_major_version, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ansible `gather_facts` is done with the [setup module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html). The `setup module` itself uses the `fact` module utilities.

- `ansible_os_family` is done in [distribution.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/distribution.py)
- `ansible_distribution_major_version` is done in [distribution.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/distribution.py)

The [ansible source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts) of the fact utilities is a good starting point for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible has multiple ways of gathering facts. By default, it tries to use all types of plugins to gather facts. You can opt either Ansible's own fact gathering plugin which is mentioned by JGK or use external program to gather facts. like this.

```
- name: Collect only facts returned by facter
  setup:
  gather_subset:
  - '!all'
  - '!any'
  - facter
```

**FACTER**

Facter is an external tool to gather facts. According to documentation, mentioning facter explicitly has the following effect:

> Runs the facter discovery program
>   (https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter) on the remote system, returning
>   JSON data that can be useful for inventory purposes.

This tool detects OS types and based on that collects further facts about that system. It depends which fact are you interested in. Based on what you are interested in you need to dig into the code to see how it is gathering facts. it is not just a single command. For Linux, you can find code for fact finding [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/tree/master/lib/src/facts/linux). Look into `operating_system_resolver.cc`. You can see that different Linux distributions have different ways of collecting facts. e.g on ubuntu it uses lsb-release command to gather few facts.

**OHAI**

Another tool which is supported by Ansible is [ohai](https://github.com/chef/ohai). Code for platform facts can found in `lib/ohai/plugins/linux/platform.rb`

Comment: Facter is only one subset of facts gathered by Ansible. If it is not available, then it will not be used.